# Parse Json response

Tags: javascript, json

I have this json response that I want to parse in Javascript.

```
[{"video_source_id":100,"title":"YouTube Top Rated"},
{"video_source_id":101,"title":"YouTube Top Favorites"}]
```

I am new to Java Script, JSON. Whats the best way to parse and display it in a webpage?

Here is what I have, but I'm getting the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

in the line

```
document.getElementById("video_source_id").innerHTML = jsonObj.video_source_id[i];
```

Full code:

```
function loadJSON()
{
    var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }catch (e) {
            try{
                http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    var data_file = "/vcaWS/api/sources";

    http_request.onreadystatechange  = function(){
        if (http_request.readyState == 4  )
        {
            // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(http_request.responseText);

            // jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can
            // be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.
            for(var i=0;i<jsonObj.length;i++){
                document.getElementById("video_source_id").innerHTML =  jsonObj.video_source_id[i];
            }
        }
    }
    http_request.open("GET", data_file, true);
    http_request.send();
}
```

Comment: You seem to be already parsing the JSON (I see `JSON.parse` in your code). Are there any problems with your code? If yes, what are they? What do you expect to happen and what does actually happen? The "best" way is the one that produces the result you want. Unfortunately we don't know what you want.

Comment: it gives error within the for loop...

Comment: And are you willing to tell us what the error is?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined .... in the line "document.getElementById("video_source_id").innerHTML =  jsonObj.video_source_id[i];"

Comment: Well, `jsonObj` is an array. Arrays don't have a `video_source_id` property. But the objects *in* the array do. So I believe you want `jsonObj[i].video_source_id`.

Comment: @FelixKling:great,write that as an answer!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonObj` is an array. Arrays don't have a `video_source_id property`. But the objects in your array do. So I believe you want `jsonObj[i].video_source_id` instead, i.e. "access the `video_source_id` property of the `i`th element in `jsonObj`".

See also: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)